# struct,template arguments, C++

Tags: c++, object-oriented, template, template-meta-programming

I am writing [color model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_model) logic in C++. I ask review in  *defining limits for the color model*, by saying **Limits** I mean this.
Consider a `struct` which represents `RGB` color model.

```
template<typename T>
struct RGB {
   T r,g,b;
};
```

So I declared a type `RGB<T>` where `T` can be any `arithmetic type` (the assertion is done, don't worry). So now I can create types `using RGB_Float = RGB<flaot>` or `using RGB_888 = RGB<unsigned char>` and so on.
As you already guessed I am doing [image processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_image_processing) and sometimes there comes a time where I want a type `RGB<float>` where each component limits are `[0-1]` and sometimes I want same `RGB<float>` with the limits `[10-20]` (An example) . Also I need each type to know its limits, at compile time. Syntax is like `RGB_Float::Limits::max() \\Returns max RGB_Float` and `RGB_Float::Limits::min() \\ Returns min RGB_Float`. So I need to change my struct `RGB<T>` this way.

```
template<typename T, typename LIMITS>
struct RGB {
    using Limits = LIMITS;
    T r,g,b;

}
```

And before declaring any `RGB<T,LIMITS>` type I need to create a struct like

```
RGB_FloatLimits {
     static RGB<float,RGB_FloatLimits> max( return {1.0f,1.0f,1.0f};
     ... // min implementation too.
}
```

And then `using RGB_Float = RGB<float,RGB_FloatLimits>;`

I know that this is a bad solution but I think it's the only if you use `C++17`. I spent a week trying to pass the limits as a template argument to a color model. Please review this solution and I am 90% sure that there is a better way to do this. Thx in advance.

**Note** In any implementation of the *limits* `sizeof` the color model must remain the same.(So we must store the max and min statically)

Comment: There is not enough code in the question to provide a good review. The question borders on hypothetical code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## C++11

Pre C++20 you have to use the type traits based approach, which is essentially what you have done. I dont think this is a bad solution, but probably the way to go if you need to.

## C++20 solution (if integral min and max are ok also for C++11 )

In C++ 20 this all becomes easier as it finally allows for class and float non-type template arguments.

```
template<typename T, T min, T max>
struct RGB {
    T r,g,b; 
}
```

works for `T = int, T = char, T = float` and so on.

This is the most straightforward solution I could think of that does not need any helper classes. If you only need `min` and `max` this is probably good.

If you could live with integer `min` and `max` then this also works pre C++20. Simply use int for the min and max template arguments.

The drawback is that in every function that accepts an RGB you need three  template parameters (`T`, `min` and `max`), which could create a lot of noise in the code and make it less readable.

#### In case you need more than two config parameters

In case `min` and `max` is not a sufficient description of the number range, you could add addtional template parameters. However I would not advise this but make the parameters now a class.

In C++20 this is very straightforward again, as you can also use class values as template parameters. This is a bit more clear than the previous type based traits approach (which is also the one you are using).

```
template <class T>
struct RGBconfig<T> {
   T min, max;
}

template<typename T, RGBconfig<T> config>
struct RGB {
    T r,g,b; 
}
```

use as

```
constexpr RGBconfig<float> float1020 = {10, 20}  

using RGBfloat1020 = RGB<float, float1020>
```

alternatively one could do

```
using RGBfloat1020 = RGB<float, RGBconfig<float> {10,20} >
```

#### Reduce to one template parameter => include type in RGBconfig

Perhaps it is even possible to reduce it down to one template argument

```
template <class T>
struct RGBconfig<T> {
   using type = T;
   T min, max;
}

template<auto config>
struct RGB {
    typename decltype(config)::type    r,g,b; 
}
```

then use as

```
constexpr RGBconfig<float> float1020 = {10, 20};
using RGBfloat1020 = RGB<float1020>;
```

or

```
using RGBfloat1020 = RGB<RGBconfig<float> {10,20} >;
```

Answer (score -1):

I would simply use a traits configuration but use a default (so it can be overridden).

```
namespace Color
{
    template<typename T>
    struct RGB_Traits;         // No definition by default

    template<typename T, typename ColourTraits = RGB_Traits<T>>
    struct RGB {
        using Traits = ColourTraits;
        T r,g,b;
    };


    template<>
    struct RGB_Traits<float>
    {
        static RGB<float>  max() {return {1.0, 1.0, 1.0};}
        static RGB<float>  min() {return {0.0, 0.0, 0.0};}
    };
    template<>
    struct RGB_Traits<unsigned char>
    {
        static RGB<unsigned char>  max() {return {255, 255, 255};}
        static RGB<unsigned char>  min() {return {0, 0, 0};}
    };

    using RGB_Float = RGB<float>;
    using RGB_888   = RGB<unsigned char>;
}

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    Color::RGB_888   data;
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(decltype(data)::Traits::max().r) << "\n";
}
```